# Office 2013 or 2016 window is cut when embedded in TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, office365, twebbrowser

I have been using TWebBrowser component in Delphi (up to XE7) to visualize and in-place edit Microsoft Office documents and it worked well with Office versions up to 2010. Unfortunately there is a visualization issue with Office 2013 or 2016. In my case the TWebBrowser is inside a TPanel and its Align property set to alClient, but the area allocated to the Office document only occupies part of the available space; besides the ribbon is too big and the text is distorted... The document can still be edited but it looks awful.

The code I used to utilize to manipulate the command bars (back in Office 2003) does not work any more with the ribbon...

So how could I fix this problem and visualize well an Office document (by the way, stored locally, not in the cloud) by hosting Office 2013 or 2016 in  Delphi's TWebBrowser?

EDIT: I do host Desktop Word for example in a TWebBrowser Control. This is my code, which works fine with Office 2010 and previous versions:

```
//Wb = name of TWEbBrowserControl
//F = name of Word document
try Wb.Navigate(F); except end;
//And to edit the document, this is a sample OnClick event of a button
procedure TForm1.pptBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
D:_Document;
begin
D:=Wb.Document AS _Document;
with D do
 begin
    Application.Selection.Paste;
    Application.Selection.TypeParagraph;
    _Release;
 end;
end;
```

EDIT: I have realized that I had created confusion with the original title referring to Office 365. Apparently this is a name for a platform with cloud-related services. Actually I meant a problem with desktop Office 2013 or 2016.

EDIT: so sorry, I also realized that I was sometimes talking about 2013 and 2016 documents being cut... That was not accurate. The problem is not with the format of the documents, but with the window of the Office application when embedded in the TWebBrowser control: if the user has Office 2010 or earlier version, no problem; if it is the latest versions, the problem of visualization arises.

EDIT: I have downgraded to Office 2010 and the problem is still there. So it must be because I am using Windows 10...

Comment: I think you miss something in your Q , what you try so far ?

Comment: I don't understand the reference to Office versions. Are you saying that you host Office 2010 desktop in a browser? That can't be right. Can you elaborate a little more as to what is hosted in what? A simple [mcve] would make life easy, then we'd know precisely what you are doing.

Comment: Hi Sierra, are you aware of the fact that TWebbrowser runs in IE7 mode and additional work needs to be done to force the browser to the most recent document mode?

Comment: @whosrdaddy I'd expect that Office 365 would do that work though. It's always easier if you control the generation of the html, and surely it does it through the response meta tags

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I wouldn't take that for granted!

Comment: I edited to be more specific about what I am doing. Please note that the issue is only for visualization of the Word document in the host TWebBrowser with Office 365. I am not very aware of the Office versions evolution, but isn't it 2003, 2007, 2010 and then 365 having two subversions, 2013 and 2016?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: That may be an issue, although as commented the problem only arises when I try to host the most recent versions of Office and only in terms of visualization. Anyhow how can you "force the browser to most recent document mode"?

Comment: OK, so this is nothing to do with Office 365, and it's just desktop office hosted in a `TWebBrowser` as an ActiveX control? Why don't you just host  Office directly in an ActiveX control and cut out the browser?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, nothing to do with Office 365, I edited the Q to correct. What I am using is the TWebBrowser that comes with Delphi and can also be imported as a type library. Is there any free ActiveX control that can be used for the same purpose?  OLE container never worked for me but TWebBrowser is excellent, only this visualization issue has arisen with newer versions. (I must say that I am an amateur programmer and don't know much.)

Comment: It's certainly possible to host office as an activex control directly. Whether or not it works well with latest versions I'm not sure but I'd be surprised if not. MS are generally good at back compat.

Comment: My monitor has resolution 2560 x 1440 and I had chosen in Windows screen configuration to scale text and applications by 150%. I changed to normal setting and the problem vanished... This is a relief... but I would still want to increase the text again, since only WebBrowser was malfunctioning... Maybe this gives someone inspiration for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to wide monitors. It was finally solved by right-clicking on the program name, selecting the “Properties” dialog, switching to the “Compatibility” tab, and checking the option “Disable display scaling on high DPI settings”.